# Bulkifying batch apex issue

Tags: apex, batch

I have issue with task creation on FHA object with a batch where FHA is parent record.
    Batch:-

```
global class fhaTaskCreationBatch implements Database.Batchable < sObject > {
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        return DataBase.getQueryLocator([select Id, OwnerId, ConveyanceDueDate__c, ICC_Date__c, ExtensionNotRequested__c, Status__c
            from FHA__c where ConveyanceDueDate__c != null
            AND(Status__c = 'Open'
                OR Status__c = 'Escalated')
            AND ICC_Date__c = NULL AND ExtensionNotRequested__c = false
            //AND Id = 'a0wQ0000009lkkH'
        ]);
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List < FHA__c > scopeFHA) {
        System.debug('FHA record : ' + scopeFHA + 'Size of FHA :' + scopeFHA.size());
        List < Task > lstTasktoInsert = new List < Task > ();
        set < Id > setOfFhaId = new set < Id > ();
        Date sevendaysbefore;

        for (FHA__c fhaO: scopeFHA) {
            sevendaysbefore = fhaO.ConveyanceDueDate__c - 7;
            setOfFHAId.add(fhaO.Id);
        }
        System.debug('7 Days before Conveyance Due Date : ' + sevendaysbefore + 'fha Id :' + setOfFHAId);

        List < Task > OpenTaskForExtension = [select Id, WhatId, Status from Task
            where Status = 'Open'
            AND Subject = 'Extension Needed'
            AND WhatId IN: setOfFHAId
        ];
        Map < string, string > fhaTaskMap = new Map < string, string > ();

        System.debug('Checking task open : ' + OpenTaskForExtension);

        if (
            sevendaysbefore == fhaObj.ConveyanceDueDate__c - 7 &&
            (OpenTaskForExtension.size() == 0)
            //&&(!fhaTaskMap.containsKey('Open'))
        ) {
            System.debug('Inside if:');
            Task taskObj = new Task();
            System.debug('fhaid ' + fhaObj.Id);

            taskObj.WhatId = fhaObj.Id;
            System.debug('ownerid ' + fhaObj.OwnerId);

            taskObj.OwnerId = fhaObj.OwnerId;
            taskObj.Subject = 'Extension Needed';
            taskObj.Status = 'Open';
            taskObj.ActivityDate = sevendaysbefore;
            taskObj.Priority = 'High';

            lstTasktoInsert.add(taskObj);
        }
        if (lstTasktoInsert.size() > 0) {
            System.debug('List Of Task Inserted :' + lstTasktoInsert);
            insert lstTasktoInsert;
        }
    }

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {

    }
}
```

Right now this batch is working on single record, but it is failing for bulk insert.

Comment: Saying *"Kindly help me ASAP"* is somewhat rude and I have removed it from your post. Please avoid such content in the future. Supplications for help or indications of the urgency of your problem are off topic and add no information that helps the community assist you. Instead, put that effort into more clearly describing your problem. Saying *"it is failing"* is quite vague and makes helping you a guessing game. Are you getting an error? If so please **[edit]** your post to include the message verbatim.

Comment: Please post the error message and some stack trace to help us identify the root cause. 

Is your Test Class also failing?

Answer (score 2):

The bulk case doesn't work because this class does not implement a bulk case. You call `lstTasktoInsert.add()` exactly zero or one time.

You seem to be missing a loop over `scopeFHA` around the `if` statement

```
    if (
        sevendaysbefore == fhaObj.ConveyanceDueDate__c - 7 &&
        (OpenTaskForExtension.size() == 0)
        //&&(!fhaTaskMap.containsKey('Open'))
    ) {
```

Additionally, the condition `OpenTaskForExtension.size() == 0` is probably wrong, since that set contains the tasks for all of the objects in scope, not just one.

Comment: Hi,I have changed the logic for this batch in the start method, with filter conditions in it now. But that batch is failing vice versa on open and non open task on an object that means the else condition is failing. I need help on this ASAP. Below is the code :

Comment: Please open a NEW question if you have a different issue, and consider accepting this answer if it solved the question. Also, please take Adrian's advice in the comments above to heart when you ask.